# OSGI equinox Servlet.init() for servlet .equinoxbridgeservlet. threw exception for Java 17

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, java-17, equinox

I have a web application that has been tested successfully with Java 8 and Java 11, but when I try to start the Tomcat server with Java 17, it throws an exception during the initial stage of the `init()` method. I attempted to address the issue by updating the runtime libraries to the latest versions, including `org.eclipse.core.runtime_3.29.0` and the servlet bridge `org.eclipse.equinox.servletbridge_1.6.300`, but the problem persists. If you have any insights or suggestions.. thanks

```
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.SystemBundleActivator.start
    .at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:800)            
    .at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:729)                     
    .at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:1002)                     
    .at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$SystemBundle$EquinoxSystemModule.initWorker(EquinoxBundle.
    .at org.eclipse.osgi.container.SystemModule.init(SystemModule.java:94)                                          
    .at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$SystemBundle.init(EquinoxBundle.java:269)                 
    .at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$SystemBundle.init(EquinoxBundle.java:254)                 
    .at org.eclipse.osgi.launch.Equinox.init(Equinox.java:168)                                                      
    .at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.startup(EclipseStarter.java:304)                            
    .at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)                              
    .at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)            
    .at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)    
    .at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)                                                  
    .at org.eclipse.equinox.servletbridge.FrameworkLauncher.start(FrameworkLauncher.java:409)                       
    .at org.eclipse.equinox.servletbridge.BridgeServlet.init(BridgeServlet.java:97)                                 
    .at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:143)                                                  
    .at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1106)                             
    .at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1063)                             
    .at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:960)                                     
    .at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4641)                           
    .at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4948)                           
    .at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)                                        
    .at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:683)                             
    .at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:658)                                     
    .at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:661)                                       
    .at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1023)                                      
    .at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1910)                                  
    .at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)                           
    .at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)                                          
    .at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)                 
    .at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:123)             
    .at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:824)                                      
    .at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:474)                                      
    .at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1617)                                          
    .at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:318)                                  
    .at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:114)                           
    .at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:402)                             
    .at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:345)                                     
    .at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:893)                                
    .at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:794)                                  
    .at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)                                                
    .at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)                       
    .at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)                   
    .at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:866)                                      
    .at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:248)                                    
    .at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)                                              
    .at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:433)                                  
    .at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)                                              
    .at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:921)                                    
    .at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)                                              
    .at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:772)                                                     
    .at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)                                    
    .at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)                  
    .at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)          
    .at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)                                                        
    .at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:347)                                                   
    .at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:478)                                                    
  Caused by: java.lang.Error: factory already defined                                                                   
    .at java.base/java.net.URL.setURLStreamHandlerFactory(URL.java:1228)                                                  
    .at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.url.EquinoxFactoryManager.installURLStreamHandlerFactory(EquinoxFactoryManager.java:39) 
    .at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.url.EquinoxFactoryManager.installHandlerFactories(EquinoxFactoryManager.java:31)        
    .at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.SystemBundleActivator.start(SystemBundleActivator.java:60)                    
    .at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:779)                           
    .at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:1)                             
    .at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:748)                                  
    .at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:772)                  
    .at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)                                                
    .at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)                       
    .at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)                   
    .at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:866)                                      
    .at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:248)                                    
    .at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)                                              
    .at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:433)                                  
    .at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)                                              
    .at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:921)                                    
    .at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)                                              
    .at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:772)                                                     
    .at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)                                    
    .at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)                  
    .at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)          
    .at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)                                                        
    .at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:347)                                                   
    .at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:478)                                                    
  Caused by: java.lang.Error: factory already defined                                                                   
    .at java.base/java.net.URL.setURLStreamHandlerFactory(URL.java:1228)                                                  
    .at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.url.EquinoxFactoryManager.installURLStreamHandlerFactory(EquinoxFactoryManager.java:39) 
    .at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.url.EquinoxFactoryManager.installHandlerFactories(EquinoxFactoryManager.java:31)        
    .at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.SystemBundleActivator.start(SystemBundleActivator.java:60)                    
    .at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:779)                           
    .at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:1)                             
    .at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:748)                                  
    .at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:772)                  
  SEVERE: Servlet .equinoxbridgeservlet. in web application ./demo. threw load() exception                               
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.SystemBundleActivator.start() of bundle org
    .at org.eclipse.equinox.servletbridge.FrameworkLauncher.start(FrameworkLauncher.java:417)                               
    .at org.eclipse.equinox.servletbridge.BridgeServlet.init(BridgeServlet.java:97)                                         
    .at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:143)                                                          
    .at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1106)                                     
    .at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1063)                                     
    .at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:960)                                             
    .at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4641)                                   
    .at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4948)                                   
    .at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)                                                
    .at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:683)                                     
    .at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:658)                                             
    .at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:661)                                               
    .at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1023)                                              
    .at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1910)                                          
    .at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)                                   
    .at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)                                                  
    .at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)                         
    .at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:123)                     
    .at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:824)                                              
    .at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:474)                                              
    .at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1617)                                                  
    .at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:318)                                          
    .at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:114)                                   
    .at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:402)                                     
    .at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:345)                                             
    .at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:893)                                        
    .at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:794)                                          
    .at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)                                                
    .at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1332)                                     
    .at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1322)
```

[image: output log (stack trace)]

Comment: Have you at least looked into what factory it is that's already defined?

Comment: Yes I did. the issue is resolved by updating equinox Common to  org.eclipse.equinox.common-3.18.100 and org.eclipse.equinox.http.registry-1.3.300